# wso2 - How to set a custom authentication URL to validate the OAuth2 user password

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a subscription for an API that is secured with OAuth2 password flow. The URL to get an access_token would be something like this:

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=<username>&password=<password>&scope=<scope1> <scope2>" -H "Authorization: Basic SVpzSWk2SERiQjVlOFZLZFpBblVpX2ZaM2Y4YTpHbTBiSjZvV1Y4ZkM1T1FMTGxDNmpzbEFDVzhh" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://localhost:8243/token
```

The https://localhost:8243/token endpoint validates de user/password against the registered users in the wso2 platform.

However in some cases I would like to be able to set a custom URL that would validate the user/password with a custom logic. Is this possible?

Comment: What kind of custom logic?

Comment: This endpoint would be a webapp that would validate the user+pass against some business rules.